# How do you structure an Express application that serves API and views?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

So I am trying to build a small application that would serve a website and also the API for it. I am using Node, Express, and Webpack for that.

The directory looks somewhat like this:

```
>client
  |>dist
  |>src
>server
  |>dist
  |>src
>node_modules
 package.json
 webpack.config.js
```

Webpack bundles everything in each `src` and spits it out in each `dist` for both `client` and `server`.

When I access `/` I want Express to serve the `index.html` file in `client/dist`. When I access `/api` I need it to do other actions (those work fine).

This is how my `server/src/app.js` file looks like (Who handles routing):

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'dist', 'index.html'));
  console.log('got hit on / boy');
});

app.get('/api/', function(req, res) { 
  //Does the right thing
})

app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on ' + port);
})
```

And my Webpack file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = [{
  name: 'Client bundling',
  entry: './client/src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'dist', 'js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty'
  }
},
{
  name: 'Server bundling',
  entry: './server/src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'server', 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty'
  },
  target: 'node'
}];
```

My follow up question would be how to access the API endpoint from the View served since they are both on the same domain.

Thank you!

Comment: Probably cleanest to put the api in it's own Express router and then use `app.use('/api', apiRouter)` to route to it.

Comment: It's trivial to access the API from the web page.  Just use an Ajax call to `/api/xxx`.

Comment: An observation, __dirname points to the current directory of the module being executed. In this case that would be `server/src/` That means 

path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'dist', 'index.html') will resolve to 

`server/src/client/dist/index.html`which does not exist.

What error or response are you getting when you hit "/"?

Comment: When I hit `/` I get `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\client\dist\index.html'` @SelloMkantjwa

Comment: @jfriend00 But even when using a separate `apiRouter` I still need to access `index.html`. How would I do that?

Comment: Huhh?  I don't understand what that last comment means?  Your non-API routes would either be served as static resources in Express or have their own router in Express, separate from the API router.  From within your page in the browser, you can only access the API with ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

You are pointing to a file that does not exist. 
Change this

`res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'dist', 'index.html')`

to this

`res.sendFile(path.resolve("../..", 'client', 'dist', 'index.html')`

Comment: Is there any reason why we're not using `__dirname`? I thought the path to files needed to be absolute.

Comment: @SammyI. `path.resolve()` always returns an absolute path. __dirname returns the directory of the current module. In your case this,  module is `server/src/app.js`, which means `__dirname` will return the absolute path  of `server/src`. Now when you merge that absolute as you have done with `path.resolve()` then it returns something like `absolute_parent_directory/server/src/client/dist/index.html` which does not exist. You are looking for `absolute_parent_directory/client/dist/index.html`, using the code in the answer will give you that.